# need to create a function that converts a range object that i created myself into a string?

Tags: javascript

below is the code that i used to create a range object within my overall programme

```
function parseRangeString(id, range) {
    var myRangeString = range;
    var myRangeStringArray = myRangeString.split(/[\s]+/);
    var myMax;
    var myMin;
    var myMinOp;
    var myMaxOp;
    var myMaxInc = false;
    var myMinInc = false;
    var op1;
    var op2;
    var cons1;
    var cons2;
    op1 = myRangeStringArray[0];
    cons1 = parseFloat(myRangeStringArray[1]);
    if (myRangeStringArray[2] != null) {
        op2 = myRangeStringArray[3];
        cons2 = parseFloat(myRangeStringArray[4]);
    }
    if (cons1 < cons2) {
        myMin = cons1;
        myMinOp = op1;
        myMax = cons2;
        myMaxOp = op2;
    } else {
        myMin = cons2;
        myMinOp = op2;
        myMax = cons1;
        myMaxop = op1;
    }
    if (myMaxOp.indexOf('=') != -1) {
        myMaxInc = true;
    }
    if (myMinOp.indexOf('=') != -1) {
        myMinInc = true;
    }
    firstRange = new Range(id, myMin, myMax, myMinInc, myMaxInc); //gives back a range object
    return firstRange;
}
```

Now i need to make another function that converts the range object to string, help needed asap because i am stuck atm!

Comment: well when im run my code at the end all i get back is [object object] so i need a function that changes object to string

Comment: what kind of string? can you give an example of input, how that maps to your variables and what the intended string should look like.

Comment: What is `Range`? The `Range` object in browsers doesn't use this API

Comment: well the user inputs ranges e.g. < -4 & < 10 and thats converted to an object cause im putting the in order smallest to largest and at the very end of the prgram when i want to alert them they are still object but objects have a built in toString so im going to create a function and call it within to string

Comment: Why do you need a string? Do you really want to display the object on the web page or do you want to work with it in your code? It's not worth it to convert it to a string for only debugging purposes, use `console.log`.

Answer (score 2):

You can overwrite the standard `toString` function on your javascript objects to make them return whatever you want. Consider this example ([demo](http://jsfiddle.net/unUaW/1/)):

```
var a = { some_property:'this could be coming from the user' }; // create a new object
a.toString = function(){
    // in here, the "this" will point to the object in "a" variable. (well, at least mot of the times)
    return this.some_property;
};
console.log(''+a); // force the object to string
```

If you create a lots of object like this, consider using the `prototype` of them to place the `toString` function, will be more efficient, MDN has [great examples](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/toString).

Comment: i want it to return the normal string that the user entered, i knew i could do that but need it to return user entered string

Comment: Well then simply store that string as a property of your `Range` object; and then have your `toString` implementation just return that value.

Comment: Updated the example to illustrate @Andrzej Doyle's point.

Answer (score -1):

Well i guess i give the same answer every day. :)

```
JSON.stringify( range );
```

Comment: so my function would be:  function parseRangeObject (range)
    {
      var myRangeString = range; JSON.stringify(myRangeString)                                        return myRangeString 
    }

Comment: No, range is your object, with JSON.stringify( range ) you create the string, with JSON.parse( rangeString ) you get your object back.

Comment: console.log( JSON.parse( JSON.stringify( { a:0, b:10 }))); just as an example

Comment: i could send you all my code if u have an email address and u culd mayb see what im talking about then

Comment: oh nevermind, I now see in the other comment that the user enters a string, thought you had the user input like two numbers and created a range object from that

Comment: no user enters strings so i need to create a function that reverses the code i have entered on the question

Comment: Ok so where is the problem now? You have a number of variables you created with your parseRangeString function, putting them in any arbitrary string is as easy as var outputString = rangeVariable1 + ":" + rangeVariables2 + ":" ... +rangeVariablen   or do I still don't get your problem?

Comment: see the code i have to create has to be re-useable so everything has to be done as functions and then the functions have to be called when needed! i could send u all my code, which wuld give u a better idea of what im trying to do